# ContentManager Out of Memory before loading any data

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, xna

I'm trying to load data in XNA, however, whenever I use the ContentManager it throws an out of memory exception. This occurs when I load my first resource. It's a 32x32 pixel image.

I'm using:

```
contentManager = (Application.Current as App).Content;
contentManager.Load<Texture2D>("Head");
```

I've been using this for ages and have no clue why it won't work now. Does anyone have any suggestions to get me past this?

Comment: Sounds silly.  But have you tried a reboot?

Comment: restarting had no effect on either my phone or the windows phone emulators. Neither did changing the build type from Debug to Release.

Comment: Then I'd make sure the resource isn't corrupted somehow.

Comment: How could I do that? I am just using a compiled png (via visual studios) content project.

Comment: After further testing this occurs even when I create a new project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've experienced this one time, it would occur consistently after coming back from a phone task (in my case it was the IAP interface).

I worked around it by delaying the content load.  My assumption was that the IAP task itself was using a lot of memory and I needed to give some time for those resources to free up before trying to allocate any more resources.

You could try adding a delay before doing the content loading (not sure when you are doing it, it should be fine if you are doing it in a place like Game.Initialize though).

Comment: I've done a bit more work with this, slowing down the loading has solved my issue. Thanks.